# Copy paste form option button in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the Excel 2007 option buttons. I have groups of yes and no so I first created a frame and placed two option buttons in them. Looks great and works great. I created another group with the same thing, a frame first and placed two option buttons in them. Both are mutually exclusive groups and work super. I have 100 rows and need 100 groups like this. If I copy paste the entire group (frame plus two option buttons), the option button number remains the same. Because of which I cannot assign a different macro to each button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this on a form or a worksheet?

Comment: I placed the options directly on the worksheet. Is there a difference between placing it in a form in a worksheet vs placing it directly on the worksheet?

Comment: I don't see that behaviour. I added a frame with two option buttons, and grouped them. If I copy/paste the group then each of the items in the pasted copy gets a new name. The option button *text* is the same as it is in the copied group, but that shouldn't affect your macro assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the control whose macro you want to change and choose `Assign Macro...`

Then choose whatever macro name you want from your list of macros or record a new one. It is up to you.

Each button is recognized separately in Excel, technically they have different IDs. While it does replicate the names of the shapes, Excel obviously realizes they are not the same. Excel conveniently assigns the same macro as you had from your copied object. It also conveniently suggests a name that is indicative of the object, using the name.

Excel repeats the names of the option buttons because it can safely do so, because they are each in different groups. If you had created all of the buttons separately they would have different names. You may notice that the Groups have different names, even though they are copied. In fact, if you were to move your option buttons out of the groups, Excel would assign new names.

You do not need to let Excel dictate your macro names, the name Excel uses to identify the object is only a guide. Use whatever macro name you like and Excel will play by your rules.